# Intent collapse with class extends from View

Tags: android

So i'm having hard time trying to figure out why when i'm trying to view the CustomView the app collapse and i have no idea why.

Basically,for now i just want it run so it doesn't matter what option you choose at the beggining when you click New Game it suppose to draw the color Red all over the screen.

From what i understands Intent only works when the class has onCreate function but still i would appreciate some explanation.

```
package com.example.omer.battleship;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private RadioGroup radioLevelGroup;
    private BoardView customView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.newGameButton);
        radioLevelGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioLevelGroup);
        customView=(BoardView)findViewById(R.id.CustomView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int selectedId = radioLevelGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                if(selectedId!=-1) {
                    OpenNewGameActivity();
                }
                }
        });
    }
    public void OpenNewGameActivity()
    {

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BoardView.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/battlepic"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioLevelGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Easy"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="139dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="209dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Large"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="263dp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="NEW GAME"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioLevelGroup" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

CustomView

```
package com.example.omer.battleship;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class BoardView extends View
{


    public BoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public BoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public BoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);

    }

    public BoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs);

    }
    private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set)
    {


    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

CustomViewXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/boardView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Ship"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onClickAddShip"
        android:layout_x="179dp"
        android:layout_y="106dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <com.example.omer.battleship.BoardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/CustomView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `BoardView` isn't an `Activity` - so you wont open it via `startActivity()`.

Add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: there's no need for a stack-trace. one simply cannot use a `View` as an `Activity`... creating a new one `Activity` which is used to display that `BoardView`; and registering it in the `Manifest.xml`... are the least conditions to be met.

Comment: @MartinZeitler There is, because "the app collapse" means the app crashes, so it will produce a log. It's probably because of that line, but there's no need to guess when there's a stacktrace

Comment: @PPartisan it might quite certainly complain, that the `Manifest.xml` has no such `Activity` registered ...which can only be registered, while it is `instanceof Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only start an activity with `startActivity(intent)` not a View!
(View is not an Activity)
Add a new Activity such as `BoardActivity` to your project and manifest then in `onCreate` of `BoardActivity` use this code:

```
public class BoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new BoardView(this));
}
```

start this activity from your MainActivity like this:

```
public void OpenNewGameActivity(){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, BoardActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);// this starts activity
}
```

---

Making your Activity full screen:

When you use `Theme.AppCompat` in your application you can use `FullScreenTheme` by adding the code below to styles.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and also change your manifest file.

```
<activity
   android:name="BoardActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1) Create a new `Activity` class. Add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. (i.e. `MyActivity`)

2) Inside `onCreate()` of your new `Activity`, add the following:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(new BoardView(this));
}
```

3) Start your `Activity`:

```
public void openNewGameActivity() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start activity using application context you need to add flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" to the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OtherActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

To start another activity from activity use your current activity context instead of application context.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```